# Print out an pdf document with ruby

Tags: ruby, printing

My program generates PDF files that I would like to print out automatically with a printer (and not in my console)! It should work on Windows operating system.  If it works on other platforms as well, then that would be perfectly fine! I considered to use Google Cloudprint, but I first would like to hear your suggestions!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608593/printing-a-file-to-a-printer-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Adobe Reader from the Windows command line.
Details are here: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=DevFAQ_UnderstandingSDK.22.31.html

Comment: Where is the exe file of adobe reader? or weher can i find it?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" is the location on a Windows 7 install.  If need a more generic solution, interrogating the Registry should work, as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891939/how-to-get-adobe-reader-full-pathincluding-executable-file-name