# Direct Printing in Rails app using system commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, system-calls, wicked-pdf

I have a method in which I'm trying to print a pdf directly from! As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608593/printing-a-file-to-a-printer-in-ruby)

I have to use **system(lpr)** command.This solutions works fine but in **ubuntu** not in windows or any other **OS**s. Do you know how to do it in **windows** ?

and this is my method:

```
def general_receipt_export
    if params[:official_id].present?
        @ids = params[:official_id].split(',')
        @officials = Official.find(@ids)
        pdf = render_to_string pdf: "#{@ids.map(&:inspect).join(',').to_s + '_receipt.pdf'}", :template => 'officials/general_receipt_export.html.erb', encoding: 'utf8',orientation: 'Landscape',page_size: 'A4'
        render layout: false
        save_path = Rails.root.join('public','pdfs', "#{@ids.map(&:inspect).join(',').to_s + '_receipt.pdf'}")
        File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
          file << pdf
        end
        system("lpr", "public/pdfs/#{@ids.map(&:inspect).join(',').to_s + '_receipt.pdf'}")
    else
       render json:{messege: 'No letter to export'},status: 404
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an easier solution which is not related to the OS you are using!
This for **Ruby**:

```
<%= link_to 'print', 'your_link_here', :onclick => 'window.print();return false;'%>
```

And it equivalence in **HTML**:

```
<a onclick="window.print();return false;" href="your_link">print</a>
```

Thank you all for putting your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

See this page for reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731926(v=ws.11).aspx you would need a Line Printer Daemon (LPD) running on the Windows Machine. And would then be able to issue the command. You might need to change some of your security settings. I have not used Rails in a Windows machine in a long time so I am not too sure if the security settings affect it.

Are you sure the machine where you are printing has a Line Printer Daemon running?

From the page I linked above:

> This example shows how to print the "Document.txt" text file to the
>   LaserPrinter1 printer queue on an LPD host at 10.0.0.45:

`Lpr -S 10.0.0.45 -P LaserPrinter1 -o Document.txt`

Hope that helps or guides you in the right direction.